# Simple program keeps exiting on final line of code C#

Tags: c#

I've been following along a book I've been studying as I'm rather new to C# and one of the projects is to create a date of birth calculator using the console template on VSC. Now i'm sure I've followed the tutorial correctly but for some reason my program close on the last line to present the entered information and outputs

> exited with code 0 (0x0)

This is what I've got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloWorldAgain
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName = "";
            int userAge = 0;
            int currentYear = 0;

            Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
            userName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Please enter your age: ");
            userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Please enter current year: ");
            currentYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! My name is {0} and I am {1} years old. I was born in {2}.", userName, userAge, currentYear - userAge);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ran it using ctrl+f5?

Comment: Write Console.ReadLine() at the end of the program and it will wait until you give any input.

Comment: If you *run* the program with F5, it won't wait at the end. Add breakpoints, `Console.ReadKey()` or debug one step at a time with F10

Comment: As close confirmation, `ReadKey(false)` is _so_ much cleaner-looking than `ReadLine()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Console applications are designed to run and exit. You should add something to prevent it from finishing before you want it to. The standard way to do this is to wait for input using:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Add the Readline() to the end of your code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World! My name is {0} and I am {1} years old. I was born in {2}.", userName, userAge, currentYear - userAge);
Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 3):

The exit 0 code means that the program has been finished without errors. After the last line, there is nothing left to execute, which means the application have done their job. If you want to keep the application "executing", you may use the trick of `Console.ReadLine()` , which simply wait to read something.

Answer (score 2):

Exiting with code 0 is perfectly normal and generally indicates your program ran successfully.

If you run a console program from visual studio with the debugger it will close the terminal window when your program completes. IF you run without the debugger it will generally keep the window open until you press a key.

If you want the terminal to stay open in the debugger then either add a breakpoint to the last line of your code or add an additional `Console.Readline` at the end of your program

Comment: Thank you for aiding the answer this extra information was also very helpful